# Individual Feature Class that jumps TO individual Feature in Webmap

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I am using the WAB(3) (Web App Builder, Beta 3) doing development of ESRI-based maps using FeatureClasses stored in our own City Government REST Services.

We currently have a program called '**Adopt-A-Spot**' where corporations/individuals can adopt a section of town for various maintenance and cleanliness provisions. What I would like is to offer a webmap with two different kinds of dots.

Dot #1 : **SPOT** - These are locations on the map that are either ADOPTED or AWAITING ADOPTION.
Dot #2 : **ADOPTER** - These are locations where the Adopter is based out of (home for individual, corporate HQ for companies)

I would like for someone clicking on an a **SPOT** to have a link that will jump to the **ADOPTER** and vice versa.

**Using the Javascript API for ESRI / Dojo / WAB(3) is there a best way of doing this?**

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what WAB(3) is?

Comment: 'web appbuilder beta 3' http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/manage-apps/deploy-app.htm